# Why is $(this).prop("id") undefined in this scenario?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I know questions similar to this wrt the confusing nature of $(this) have been asked many times before, but I still couldn't figure this out reading through them; apologies in advance if this is really simple / already answered elsewhere.

I have an input form with an autocomplete which gets its suggestions from a JSON file.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>HTML Form</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="example" id="example">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Then I have some javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").autocomplete({
        source: function () {
            console.log($(this).prop("id"));
            var suggestions = [];
            $.getJSON("parameters.json", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if (key == $(this).prop("id")) {
                        suggestions = val;

                    }
                });
            })
            return suggestions;
        }
    });

    $("#example").keyup(function () {
        console.log($(this).prop("id"));
    })
});
```

The `console.log($(this).prop("id"));` in the `$("#example").keyup()` event handler binder outputs "example", as expected. However, the `console.log($(this).prop("id"));` in the code for the autocomplete widget outputs `Undefined`. Why is this happening? If I remove the `.prop("id")` from both then they return
[image: JQuery Objects]

Where the top object is outputted from the keyup and the bottom is from the autocomplete.

Could anyone explain the discrepancy here? Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use $(this).prop on something that isn't a dom element? it's just an object... access it's properties like any other object.

Comment: Oh, i see, that's your problem. You expected `this` to refer to the input element... but it in fact does not. You mightaswell just do `key === 'example'`, id's shouldn't be changing anyway. Otherwise, you'll need to bind that function (and the one above it) such that it has the expected `this`.

Comment: `$(this)` is `undefined`. `this` within the function passed to the `source` property of the autocomplete options **is not** the `input` on which the autocomplete is instantiated, but the function itself.

Comment: Inside `$.each()`, `this` refers to the current object in the iteration, it's the same as `val`.

Comment: You know what's the `id`... Why do you want to use `this` anyway?

Comment: Why do you need to use `$(this).prop('id')` in the first place? You bind the handler to a specific ID, it will always be `example`.

Comment: In my actual the one autocomplete is going to be used for multiple inputs, that's why I don't have it addressed by id

Answer (score -1):

You can interrogate the `$(this)` object to find what you're looking for. Using `console.log($(this))` jQuery returns an array containing one object. That object includes a another array of objects called "elements" which contains a reference to the `<input>` element.

I used `$(this)[0].element[0].id` instead of `$(this).prop("id")` and it worked, even when I added multiple `<input>` elements and bound the autocomplete function by class rather than ID.

**EDIT**

To further my answer - which is likely to be more useful that the oblique references and dismissals provided by some others. The following will handle the callback issue described by @Barmar and will allow to you get access to the ID as you describe.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#example").autocomplete({
        source: function () {
            var suggestions = [];
            var elementId = $(this)[0].element[0].id;
            $.getJSON("parameters.json", function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    console.log(elementId);
                    if (key == elementId) {
                        suggestions = val;
                    }
                });
            });
            return suggestions;
        }
    });

    $("#example").keyup(function () {
        console.log($(this).prop("id"));
    });
});
```

The variable `elementId` catches the ID while the `$(this)` is still in the correct context and makes it available to the delegate functions resulting from `$.getJSON` and `$.each`. In my example, `elementId` would be written out to console for each returned key/val pair.

Comment: When you call a jQuery method that returns information on a collection, it automatically returns it from the first element. You don't need to index it yourself.

Comment: the problem in the question is that `this` doesn't refer to the element at all.

Comment: You're right that `$(this)` doesn't refer directly to the element but it does include a reference to the element which is easily accessible. Agree with the short hand re: not requiring an index. Disagree with your understanding of the OP's problem and requirement.

Comment: The problem is that he's using `$(this).prop('id')` inside `$.each`. In that callback, `this` is the current element of the `data` array, not a DOM element at all. I've marked this as a duplicate of a question that explains how to access the outer `this` variable.